# Name of this formula or more explantation of the proof?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binary

I have found this formula which is a combinatorial identity for counting binary words. I'd like more information on it, or the name of the proof. I am also not totally clear on the step between the identity and the equivalent identity. Any ideas?

The formula:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{n + k}{n}2^{-k} = 2^{n}$$

The proof is a counting proof using this equivalent identity:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{n + k}{n}2 \cdot 2^{n-k} = 2^{2n + 1}$$

EDIT: I found the source in Pearls of Discrete Mathematics, example 3.4 [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=v07RBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=choices+for+the+remaining+n-k+elements+this+establishes+the+identity&source=bl&ots=D5XcY4uLCS&sig=k8OVaOlr_bUbVxzEioO_NBiHUnk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfgaDH_8_KAhVGn4MKHRbzAzUQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=choices%20for%20the%20remaining%20n-k%20elements%20this%20establishes%20the%20identity&f=false)

Comment: Multiply by $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Your second identity is not typed correctly.  Instead of $2^{-k}$, it should be $2^{n-k}$.

Comment: **Hint:** $~\displaystyle{n+k\choose n}~=~{n+k\choose k}~=~(-1)^k~{-n-1\choose k}.$